# How to add new requests for my Scrapy Spider during crawling

Tags: python, scrapy

I use the XMLFeedSpider in Scrapy to scrap a real estate website.

Each url request generated by my spider (via start_urls) return a page in XML with a bunch of ads and a link to the next page (search results is limited to 50 ads).

I was therefore wondering how i could add this additional page as new request in my spider ?

I've been searching through stackoverflow for a while but i just can't find a simple answer to my problem !

Below is the code i have in my spider. I have updated it with the parse_nodes() method mentioned by Paul but the next url is not picked up for some reasons.

Could i yield additional requests in the adapt_response method ?

```
from scrapy.spider import log
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from crawler.items import RefItem, PicItem
from crawler.seloger_helper import urlbuilder
from scrapy.http import Request

class Seloger_spider_XML(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'Seloger_spider_XML'
    allowed_domains = ['seloger.com']
    iterator = 'iternodes' # This is actually unnecessary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'annonce'  

'''Spider Initialized with department as argument'''
def __init__(self, departement=None, *args, **kwargs):
    super(Seloger_spider_XML, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    #self.start_urls = urlbuilder(departement) #helper function which generate start_urls
    self.start_urls = ['http://ws.seloger.com/search.xml?cp=72&idtt=2&tri=d_dt_crea&SEARCHpg=1']

def parse_node(self, response, node):

    items = []
    item = RefItem()  

    item['ref'] = int(''.join(node.select('//annonce/idAnnonce/text()').extract()))
    item['desc'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/descriptif/text()').extract()).encode('utf-8')
    item['libelle'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/libelle/text()').extract()).encode('utf-8')
    item['titre'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/titre/text()').extract()).encode('utf-8')
    item['ville'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/ville/text()').extract()).encode('utf-8')
    item['url'] =''.join(node.select('//annonce/permaLien/text()').extract()).encode('utf-8')
    item['prix'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/prix/text()').extract())
    item['prixunite'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/prixUnite/text()').extract())
    item['datemaj'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/dtFraicheur/text()').extract())[:10]
    item['datecrea'] = ''.join(node.select('//annonce/dtCreation/text()').extract())[:10]
    item['lati'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/latitude/text()').extract()))
    item['longi'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/longitude/text()').extract()))
    item['surface'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/surface/text()').extract()))
    item['surfaceunite'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/surfaceUnite/text()').extract()))
    item['piece'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/nbPiece/text()').extract())).encode('utf-8')
    item['ce'] = (''.join(node.select('//annonce/dbilanEmissionGES/text()').extract())).encode('utf-8')

    items.append(item)

    for photos in node.select('//annonce/photos'):
            for link in photos.select('photo/thbUrl/text()').extract():
                pic = PicItem()
                pic['pic'] = link.encode('utf-8')
                pic['refpic'] = item['ref']
                items.append(pic)

    return items

    def parse_nodes(self, response, nodes):
        for n in super(Seloger_spider_XML, self).parse_nodes(response, nodes):
            yield n
    # once you're done with item/nodes
    # look for the next page link using XPath
    # these lines are borrowed form
    # https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py#L73
        selector = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        self._register_namespaces(selector)
        for link_url in selector.select('//pageSuivante/text()').extract():
            yield Request(link_url)
```

Thank you
Gilles

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can override the `parse_nodes()` method to hook in your "next page" URL extraction.

The example below is based on [Scrapy docs XMLFeedExample](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#xmlfeedspider-example):

```
from scrapy import log
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import XMLFeedSpider
from myproject.items import TestItem
from scrapy.selector import XmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySpider(XMLFeedSpider):
    name = 'example.com'
    allowed_domains = ['example.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/feed.xml']
    iterator = 'iternodes' # This is actually unnecessary, since it's the default value
    itertag = 'item'

    def parse_node(self, response, node):
        log.msg('Hi, this is a <%s> node!: %s' % (self.itertag, ''.join(node.extract())))

        item = Item()
        item['id'] = node.select('@id').extract()
        item['name'] = node.select('name').extract()
        item['description'] = node.select('description').extract()
        return item

    def parse_nodes(self, response, nodes):
        # call built-in method that itself calls parse_node()
        # and yield whatever it returns
        for n in super(MySpider, self).parse_nodes(response, nodes):
            yield n

        # once you're done with item/nodes
        # look for the next page link using XPath
        # these lines are borrowed form
        # https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/contrib/spiders/feed.py#L73
        selector = XmlXPathSelector(response)
        self._register_namespaces(selector)
        for link_url in selector.select('//pageSuivante/text()').extract():
            print "link_url", link_url
            yield Request(link_url)
```

Comment: Thank you, i just added my code and tried to insert the parse_nodes. It looks like the next page is not parsed for some reason. Any idea ?. Should i try to yield additional page by inserting Request in "adapt_response" method which i think is called before parse_nodes as well?

Comment: I edited the example code at the end to use `text()` nodes, `.extract()` on the selector, and `.strip()` on the URL before using it in `Request()`

Comment: In fact, `.strip()` is not necessary

Comment: Thank you. I have added the missing text() and extract() but the parse_nodes seems to stop after "yield n" and ignore the "yield request"(I have checked the "select" in the scrapy shell and it works). Any idea?

Comment: unless you share your new code, I don't see what's wrong, I was able to make it work. Post it to gist.github.com or pastebin and share the link.

Comment: I have amended my code above. That's my code currently. After running my spider, i get "downloader/request_method_count/GET': 1," in the stats. Do you get 4 ?

Comment: I think it has to do with the indentation level of your `parse_nodes()`; it needs to be aligned with `parse_node()`. Try this version: https://gist.github.com/redapple/b0ecb56797c1b7abe076

Comment: It is indeed! I didn't realise that parse_nodes was actually in parse_node. Thanks very much for your help on this. Much appreciated :)